# Post-processing of the image failed

Tags: images, media, media-library

When uploading 8 pictures via Media, Add New, I get this error:

```
    Post-processing of the image failed. If this is a photo or
 a large image, please scale it down to 2500 pixels and upload it again.
```

The images are about 400KB to 700KB, so are not huge. Those images are processed via Postie, but also fail with the above message when I manually add the images via Media, Add New. Other images with the same dimensions (3888 x 5184px approx) upload and process normally. I also tried to upload the 'problem' image files singly, but the same error.

I have increased the max_upload_size to 128MB, and the max_post_time to 300, but no fix.

Some research seems to indicate that it's a problem with the large image processor added to 5.3, and say to add this line to the functions.php file to disable it.

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

So I did that, then tried to upload the same 8 files again via Media, Add New, but still get the failure on the same two files.

There is some discussion about this new feature here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/11/updates-to-image-processing-in-wordpress-5-3/ .

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any solutions?

Comment: Maybe some of the solutions here could help you, I haven't tried any: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849039/wordpress-image-upload-time-error-post-processing-of-the-image-failed

Comment: Been there, done that, no t-shirt.

Comment: Please try to save the image again, outside WordPress in an image editor. I see it here and there that the image format is broken and then you get the same error message.